# Can Axis2 expose a web service from a plain old Java program?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I need to modify an existing Java SE process to expose a web service.

I notice that ApacheCXF can expose web services from a Java SE process, but my company is pushing me strongly towards using Axis2.

All the examples seem to assume you're running a fully-fledged servlet container. But since Java SE 6 includes com.sun.net.httpserver, I was hoping there'd be a way of avoiding setting up something like Jetty or Tomcat.

How can I use Axis2 to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axis 2 web services, including [JAX-WS web services](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_4_1/jaxws-guide.html#DeployService), need to be packaged and deployed in the Axis 2 container (the Axis 2 web application itself is a container for Web Services). So you have your answer, Axis 2 has to run inside a servlet container.

While I understand the motivations behind Axis 2 "container like" architecture and its deployment model, I really hate it and see more drawbacks than advantages (like its packaging hell which is totally counter productive). If at least it was performing better than alternatives, but no! See [this comparison with the RI](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/02/jaxws_ri_21_ben.html) for example. Really, if you can reconsider using Axis 2, do it.

Comment: Thanks Pascal.  So does this mean that Axis2 has to run inside a servlet container?

Comment: @philharvey Yes, this is what it means